# Export photos My sites between trusted farms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, server-farm, sharepoint-farm

I have a  farm with user profiles and my sites configured.

There is a two trust between the two farms. When I am  trying to start the user profile synchronization service I had to use the IP address of the domain controller as the name could be resolved and it kept saying LDAP server is unavailable.

The user profile service is working  and  the profiles have imported successfully.

1. I edited the user profile properties to import the user photos which
   seems to be working now.
2. When I edited the picture property and set the direction to
   export. The  crawl showed success in the FIM logs for DC_export and
   the photos where not exported.

I have SSL certificates added to the web front ends. I have also configured AAM.

In the logs I get following errors:

- Is there any article which details how to configure the MIISClient to
  check if the export property is actually being exported.
- Is there any article which gives provides information if this issue
  is caused by SSL certificates.

  > User Profile Application: SynchronizeMIIS encounters an exception:
  >   System.NullReference
  >
  > ```
  >     Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
  >      at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.<>c__DisplayClass2.
  >
  >     <IsTimerJobRunning>b__1()  
  >        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.
  >
  >     <RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
  >      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
  >
  >
  >     secureCode) 
  >         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
  >
  >
  >     secureCode, Object param)  
  >        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
  >
  >
  >     secureCode)    
  >      at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.IsTimerJobRunning
  >
  >     (UserProfileApplicationJob timerJob) 
  >       at Microsoft.Office.Server....  e14cf29c-3eae-0052-f803-6f87d11502318
  >
  >
  >
  >     EditProprty::_BuilDSMappingList threw exception : System.IO.InvalidDataException: 
  >
  >     Found invalid data while decoding.
  >          at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Synchronization.DSMLAttribute.get_Syntax()
  >
  >      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.EditProperty._BuildDSMappingList
  >
  >     (SortedList& attributes, Hashtable& propertyDefinitions, Boolean& fHasImports, 
  >     Boolean& fHasExports, Boolean& fHasImportFromSelectedConnection)  
  >
  >     f74cf29c-0e66-0052-f803-6079ba0a6928
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

From SharePoint side

- Open MIISCLIENT.EXE from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office
  Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell
- Look at the latest DS_EXPORT phase and click on "Updates" in Export
  Statistics, this would open the Object Details window
- Choose the user for whom the picture was updated and click on
  Properties
- You should see a change of type "add" for attribute name
  "thumbnailPhoto" as below[image]

http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2012/02/21/how-to-sync-picture-from-sharepoint-to-active-directory-and-hence-to-outlook-and-lync.aspx

Comment: I am still fizzy about the using the IP address of the Domain controller

Comment: Do you think I need to add the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services |to the Application server on which the user profile is configured. http://www.rajeshg.me/2013/09/ldap-server-is-unavailable-in.html.  Is this a recommended practice in a production environment.

Comment: I changed the IP address to the server name on the server connection page but the full synchronization shows 0 updates.